# Am I correctly finding the standard matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> **Question:**
>
> Let $F: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ be the linear transformation satisfying
>   $F(1,0,1)=(-3,-3,1)$,$F(0,1,0)=(0,1,1)$, and $F(0,1,1)=(2,-2,1)$. Find
>   the standard matrix $A$ of $F$.

**My Approach:**

I used a method that I haven't been taught, so I'm not sure if I am correct and allowed to do this. Can you guys see if this is acceptable.

Since:

$$F\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3\\-3\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$F\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$F\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2\\-2\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

We want to find:

$$\text{standard matrix:}F\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}=?$$

So what I did was:

[image]

$$\therefore \text{standard matrix:}F\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3&0&2\\-1&0&-1\\-2&1&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

**Is this method correct?**

Comment: @MSE, please consider converting image to text (the question, mainly), or it will not be searchable/may be flagged to close.

Comment: @JessePFrancis I don't know how to write that picture in latex, where there are two boxes beside each other. I have put the stuff I can in latex.

Comment: @JessePFrancis Is it better now? :)

Comment: Just use array with {ccc|ccc} param for double matrices.

Comment: @JessePFrancis Did that as well :)

Comment: I found out what you calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check your solution,

So you got $T(1,0,0)=(3,-1,-2)$, $~T(0,1,0)=(0,0,1)$ and $~T(0,0,1)=(2,-1,-1)$

Now $T(1,0,1)=(3,-3,1)$

also $~T(1,0,1)=T(e_1+0.e_2+e_3)=Te_1+Te_3=(3,-1,-2)+(2,-1,-1)=(5,-2,-3) \not=(3,-3,1).$

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix does not map $(0,1,0)^t$ to $(0,1,1)^t$, so I believe it is wrong.

Instead you could use
$$
A X = Y \iff \\
A = Y X^{-1}
$$
where $X$ has the given argument vectors and $Y$ the corresponding image vectors, assuming the argument vectors are linear independent.

Applying the above I get
$$
X =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 &0 & 0 \\
0 &1 & 1 \\
1 &0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\quad\quad
Y=
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
 3 & 0 &  2 \\
-3 & 1 & -2 \\
 1 & 1 &  1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which leads to
$$
A=
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1&0&2\\
0&1&-3\\
1&1&0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The matrix you calculated is $B = X^{-1} Y$. It solves $X B = Y$.

Comment: +1 Hey, Did you mean F(A) ? how do I test my matrix?

Comment: okay ummm. First off all, is my method correct?

Comment: My book definition: Let $F:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ be a L.T. Then the standard matrix A for F is the unique m x n matrix such that: $$F(x)=Ax$$.